# add multiple proxy in package json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, proxy

I'm using two servers for my react app, one for express and the other one that come with create-react-app. So in the react side server in package.json I added :

```
"proxy": {
    "/auth/google": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
```

I run the server and I got this error :

```
When specified, "proxy" in package.json must be a string.
Instead, the type of "proxy" was "object".
Either remove "proxy" from package.json, or make it a string.
```

How can I fix that ? How can I add proxy ? Maybe using other syntax ?

Answer (score 5):

The use of advanced proxy settings is deprecated in create-react-app v2. If you’re not using a string, but, like in your case, an object, you’ll have to use [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) and set up a *setupProxy.js* file in your *src/* folder.

1. First, install [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) using npm or Yarn:

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
# or
yarn add http-proxy-middleware
```

2. Then, create *src/setupProxy.js* and add the following:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }))
}
```

More on this issue: [Move advanced proxy configuration to src/setupProxy.js](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5103)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's too late now but i found this solution and i want to share it!
to add multiple proxies in your `package.json` 
you wanna install this package:

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware
```

Then create a file in your src folder named `setupProxy.js`
and then add the following code to it:

```js
const proxy=require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api/putobject',{target:'http://server1.com'})),
    app.use(proxy('/api/getobject',{target:'http://server2.com'})),
    app.use(proxy('/api/deleteobject',{target:'http://server3.com'}))
}
```

Ofcourse replace your servers and your endpoints.

I hope it helps :)